# How to Change WPF listview Header background color

Tags: wpf, xaml

[image]

How I can change remaining header background color in listview WPF C#.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can apply a style to `GridViewColumnHeader`

For example :

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Transparent">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ContentHeader" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="5,5,5,0" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
</Style>
```

and

```
<ListView VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="63" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1}" >
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```